# Vue3 <component> tag does not emit events or work with v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

```
<component is="input" v-model="myModel"/>
```

Does not update the v-model or emit any `update:modelValue` event

```
<input v-model="myModel"/>
```

Works totally fine though. Is there something i'm missing or do `<component>` elements not work with Vue3 events?

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
<component is="input" v-model:value="myModel"/>
```